# Is it possible to pay a visit to only ONE synagogue in Prague?

Tags: fees-and-charges, prague

After seeing photos of the Prague Spanish synagogue, I decided to go for a vist, only to be asked there to pay for a ticket for 6 sights! The cost being 330 CZK or about 15 USD which might be a deal if you actually want to visit that many of them but is very expensive for one. It's kind of like being asked to pay for the whole menu when you just want shrimp.

**Is it possible to pay a lesser amount to visit a single synagogue?**

Actually, shouldn't there be a time when access is *free*? Most churches anywhere in the world (OK, in over 50 countries I've been too) are free and most of the rest usually charge a very small fee. Why do synagogues charge for entrance (they did too in Brazil, only much less)?

Comment: My personal view is if you go to Prague you should be seeing the 6 sights and even more.  Otherwise you are sacrificing the experience in lieu of a scant monetary benefit, why go at all?  And don't forget the Dvorak Museum. It rocks.

Comment: The ticketed synagogues of Prague are frankly more museums than operating religious institutions. I believe the Old-New Synagogue does host some religious services, but otherwise they really aren't the same thing as operating churches, which are financed by parishioners and/or a central institution. These sites charge for entrance because it costs money to maintain the historic buildings, staff them, provide security, etc...

Comment: Is that "sites," "sights," or both?  :-). In Spain, some churches (and museums) are free and some are not.  Helps me decide which ones to visit.

Comment: I don't even like shrimp !

Comment: Just don't take shrimps into the synagogue.

Comment: Part of the history you learn in the synagogues is why there is no longer much demand for services. :-(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is it possible to pay a lesser amount to visit a single synagogue?

All the synagogues are managed by a single Jewish organization and from their website it's quite clear [you only have 3 options](http://www.jewishmuseum.cz/en/info/visit/admission/):

1. Maisel Synagogue / Pinkas Synagogue / Old Jewish Cemetery / Klausen Synagogue / Ceremonial Hall / Spanish Synagogue / Old-New Synagogue - for 500 CZK.
2. Maisel Synagogue / Pinkas Synagogue / Old Jewish Cemetery / Klausen Synagogue / Ceremonial Hall / Spanish Synagogue  (without the Old-New Synagogue) - 330 CZK
3. Old-New Synagogue - 200 CZK

So the only synagogue where you can pay separately is the Old-New Synagogue and at 200 CZK it's not much of a bargain.  Another option is to purchase the [Prague Card](https://www.praguecard.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=7&Itemid=106&lang=en), which gives free access to all the synagogues + numerous museums and works as a public transport ticket.

> Actually, shouldn't there be a time when access is free?

There are occasional ceremonies at the synagogues, but as far as I can tell they're only open to community members. Very few Jews live in Prague so they're not "open house" like the churches might be.

Comment: Many churrches do not want tourists in during services, often even kicking paying visitors out (or out of most of the building) when services start. I can imagine Jews not wanting crowds in the Synagoges while they have their services either.